# How to convert individual tabs in google sheets into PDF

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Does anyone know if its possible to convert individual tabs within the sheet into pdf documents using the tab links? So I wanted to write an apps script that could read the individual tab link of each row and create an individual PDF file which can be stored in drive.
[Project Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7mxw.png)

Currently I am using this code but it will convert the entire workbook into PDF.

````
  if (index===0) return;
  if (row[8]) return; 
  if (row[0]=="") return; 

  const projectDate = new Date(row[1]).toLocaleDateString();

  const sheet2 =**SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(row[7])**;
  const blobPDF = sheet2.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(`${row[0]} - ${projectDate}`);
  var url = pdfFile.getUrl();
  sheet.getRange(index + 1, 9).setValue(url);```
````

Comment: In your question, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/39322260

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create mass create PDFs based on worksheet tab link. Skip those that are already created using forEach loop

```
rows.forEach(function(row, index){
  if (index===0) return;
  if (row[11]) return; 
  if (row[0]=="") return; 

  //Convert dates into proper date forms
  const projectDate = new Date(row[1]).toLocaleDateString();

  //To create a way to read the unique GID of each tab going down the sheet
  const url ='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nCbWJnbt7xRHRBlLFGgpFMXEzKscIlro4tLs6HzMXCU'
  +'/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=A3'                           // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=false'                    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=false'                        // fit to page width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
  + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  + '&gid=' + `${row[10]}`;              // the sheet's Id



 const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  // request export url
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });


// To create mass create individual PDFs based on each link
  const blobPDF = response.getBlob();
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(`${row[0]} - ${projectDate}`);
  var urllink = pdfFile.getUrl();
  sheet.getRange(index + 1, 12).setValue(urllink);

  
  })
```